# my second div where I put my unordered list not displaying ?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a To-Do list app and when I'm getting to the second div where I want to create the unordered list, it is not displaying and I don't seem to know why it is not displaying. I've tried erasing that div and creating a enw one and writing a simple hello message but not even that displays. I'm guessing it has something to do with the first div for not allowing it.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
      <title>To Do list</title>

    <style type="text/css">

        #topBar-div{
            background-color: #F44336;
            position:absolute;
            top: 0px;
            width:100%;
            height: 150px;

        }

        body{
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }

        h1{
            color:white;
            margin-left: 300px;
        }

        #textInput{
            height: 30px;
            margin-left: 100px;
            width: 600px;
            font-size: 20px;
            color: #8E8E8E;
        }

        #addButton{
            height:37px;
            position:relative;
            top:-4px;
            right: 5px;
            width: 70px;
            color: grey;

        }

        #secondBar-div{
            color: grey;
            height: 350px;
            width: 1000px;
        }


    </style> 

</head>

<body>
    <div id="topBar-div">

        <h1>My To Do List</h1>

        <input type="text" value="Title..." id="textInput">

        <button id="addButton">Add</button>

    </div>

    <div id="secondBar-div">

        <ul>

            <li>Hit the gym</li>
            <li>Pay bills</li>
            <li>Meet George</li>
            <li>Buy eggs</li>
            <li>Study</li>
            <li>Cook Dinner</li>

        </ul>


    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove the first div `position:absolute;`? OR position the second one?

Comment: Note when you use  `position:absolute;` it takes the div out of the "flow" and thus the second div gets positioned at the top left by default since nothing is "ahead" of it in the flow.  It IS there, just behind the other one, positioned at the same place.  So you have to move the second one down below the first one since that first "block" is not taken into account.

Answer (score 2):

You are using position absolute in the style of the first div (topBar-div) so your second div (secondBar-div) moves up and is actually behind that first div.

Try adding this to #secondBar-div

```
margin-top: 150px;
```